# How to set up DAAP sharing in Banshee?

Tags: music, sharing, banshee, daap

Ok, so I can see and listen to music libraries from other computers on my network via Banshee (They are running Rhythmbox with DAAP enabled) but I cannot see my Banshee library from them.

I have DAAP enabled in plugins (on Banshee).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Banshee still doesn't have DAAP sharing. It can consume, but there's no DLNA server in there yet.

According to the [application selection blueprints for Natty](https://blueprints.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+spec/packageselection-desktop-n-application-selection), the Ubuntu developers wan't to "fix UPNP support". I take that to mean making Banshee comparable to RhythmBox but there's room for misinterpretation.

The Banshee Team recommended method is through an external application called Tangerine. This has the benefit over an embedded solution in that Banshee wouldn't need to be running for things to find music. An image of its settings UI running shows below.

[image]

Comment: Where did you hear that DAAP in Banshee was a targeted feature? We (the Banshee team) have always been against inclusion in Banshee, and of the belief that it makes more sense to be an external daemon, like Tangerine.

Comment: @Alex From a Natty integration POV, I read ["fix upnp support"](https://blueprints.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+spec/packageselection-desktop-n-application-selection) to mean this. I do now see that integrating DAAP back into Banshee isn't desired from Team Banshee's POV but surely there's a compromise somewhere? Would it not be possible to launch tangerine's settings UI from within Banshee (if installed) and show sharing status in Banshee?

Comment: I also see there's conversation on the gnome bugzilla about hooking in Rygel.

Comment: It's worth mentioning that Tangerine is on the Ubuntu Software Center and so it dead easy to install.

Comment: Streaming via Tangerine doesn't stream the multi-artists of compilations and it doesn't stream the album covers. That's why it would be better, if Banshee would have an own DAAP-Server ;-)

Answer (score 3):

Best thing to do is install `mt-daapd`. This is a daemon which broadcasts a DAAP share and can be configured through a web interface or by editing a text file. To install, type the following in the command line:

`sudo apt-get install mt-daapd`

To configure, navigate with your browser to:

http://localhost:3689

with

```
username: mt-daapd
password: mt-daapd
```

You can change these once you are on the web interface.
From there on it's pretty simple, and the interface should be self explanatory.