# Streaming a playing song to other users via Banshee or Rhythmbox

Tags: 11.10, banshee, rhythmbox

Is there a way to stream to my friends the song I am listening to in banshee or rhythmbox. I am not only asking for the ability to show what song I am listening to which works already by activating the Telepathy extension, but also to have a way to let them hear it while I play it. When I play a song they can also hear it on their PCs.

Comment: should this song be heard in sync?

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://askubuntu.com/q/28039/10698

Comment: @Alvar - That would accomplish the same objective but in this case I am asking how to do it with Banshee or Rhythmbox, not by tunning pulseaudio or installing a Daemon.

Comment: ok, will be fun to see if you get a working answer...

Comment: I am not sure about the in sync part, but linux is modular, so you need a server of some kind, You can use extensions or other servers. See : http://askubuntu.com/questions/11147/setting-up-daap-in-banshee and http://www.webupd8.org/2010/03/banshee-telepathy-extension-allows-you.html

Comment: Just read your posts bodhi. In both I can only share my library but not share the song I am listening to. It actually does not matter if the way to do this is an extension or something else the thing is, I want to play a song in Banshee or Rhythmbox and make it so a friend in another country hears the song in his empathy or banshee or whatever he has connected.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The task you are asking for is setting up an internet radio stream. This can best be achieved by running an combination of [Icecast2](http://packages.ubuntu.com/icecast2) with [Ices2](http://packages.ubuntu.com/ices2) (for OGG Vorbis streams) or [Darkice](http://packages.ubuntu.com/darkice) (for mp3).

By this doing so we are able to broadcast the sound of our local sound card over the internet using a well established and stable protocol independent of local music players  used (you could even broadcast the sound from a microphone).

See also [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/28498/3940) for a guide to a basic setup or visit the [Icecast documentation site](http://www.icecast.org/docs/icecast-trunk/) for further details.

Answer (score 3):

**[Telepathy Extension for Banshee](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/banshee-extension-telepathy)**

*This may not be a complete answer, but it's a start...*

If you are using Banshee and your friend is also using Banshee, and you're both on computers that can use [Telepathy](http://telepathy.freedesktop.org/wiki/), you can share your entire library with them using the `banshee-extension-telepathy` available in the Software Center.

This is similar to [DAAP for iTunes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_Audio_Access_Protocol), except that it is not limited to your local network -- it can stream the music over the internet.

It's worth noting that this doesn't only share the song you are currently listening to (though it can *show* the current song in your chat status) -- it makes your whole library available.

Comment: I added that Michael. As you say it is a good start because this is to let people know the benefits of free software like library sharing. I actually did not know about the sharing stuff until yesterday when I was looking for a way to share the song I was playing to other users so they too could listen to it and confused "streaming" in the contact list in Banshee with "streaming" as in "Stream the song you are listening too to other empathy users". For the moment I am looking for a way to let others listen to the playing song but please do not delete your answer as it also helps and relates.